# How to merge 2 partitions on macOS

Tags: macos, high-sierra, partition

I have an MBP running macOS High Sierra. There are 2 partitions. How can I get rid of BC1, and merge the space into Macintosh HD? Know very little about macOS. Please help. Thanks!

[image: Disk Utility]

[image: diskutil list]

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the answer.

1. Open Disk Utility
2. Select the root of Internal drive on the left pane.
3. Click Partition button on the top pane.
4. Delete un-wanted partition(s).

It's easy if you know!

[image: Disk Utility]